# \renewcommand with exact same definition results in weird error

Tags: macros, dramatist

I'm using the `dramatist` package to typeset a drama script. Characters are created using the `\GCharacter`-command. I want to customize that command to have it execute `\NewPerson` for each new Character created.

To do so, I've looked up the installed `dramatist.sty` on my system and copied the definition of `\GCharacter` into my preamble like that:

```
\renewcommand\GCharacter[3]{
    \stepcounter{g\Roman{character}}
    \global\@namedef{#3}{{\namefont #2}\xspace}
    \global\n@me@ppend@nddef{#3}{\@ppendname}{%
        \if@drverse
            {\speakstab\speaksfont #2\speaksdel\par\nobreak\addvspace{-\parskip}}
        \else
            \item[#2\speaksdel]
        \fi}
    \global\n@me@ppend@nddef{gpersona@\Roman{character}}{%
        @\Roman{g\Roman{character}}}{\castfont #1}
}
```

This is the exact definition from the `dramatist.sty`-file. However, LaTeX complains: `! You can't use \spacefactor in vertical mode.` on the first line I use `\GCharacter` in. How could this be, as I've changed nothing in comparison to the original definition?

In the following MWE, the error occurs in line 19:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\GCharacter[3]{
    \stepcounter{g\Roman{character}}
    \global\@namedef{#3}{{\namefont #2}\xspace}
    \global\n@me@ppend@nddef{#3}{\@ppendname}{%
        \if@drverse
            {\speakstab\speaksfont #2\speaksdel\par\nobreak\addvspace{-\parskip}}
        \else
            \item[#2\speaksdel]
        \fi}
    \global\n@me@ppend@nddef{gpersona@\Roman{character}}{%
        @\Roman{g\Roman{character}}}{\castfont #1}
    %\NewPerson
}

\begin{CharacterGroup}{TeX.SX}
\GCharacter{A Character}{A Character}{character}
\end{CharacterGroup}

\begin{document}
\DramPer

\lipsum[1] % Compilation fails with only \DramPer in document
\end{document}
```

Without the `\renewcommand`, everything works fine: [image: My MWE]

Any clues on how to fix that error?

Comment: Add `\makeatletter` before the `\renewcommand` and `\makeatother` after the `\renewcommand...` such that it reads `\makeatletter\renewcommand\GCharacter[3]{...}\makeatother`

Comment: you could just have used the search box for that error http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%21+You+can%27t+use+%5Cspacefactor+in+vertical+mode

Comment: You should consider `\patchcmd` instead of `\renewcommand` (but that does not prevent the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair)

Comment: I did a lot of search regarding customizing macros from packages and so on, but I didn't stumble upon the `@`-thing. Sorry about that. @Christian Hupfer: What are the advantages of `\patchcmd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter % here
\renewcommand\GCharacter[3]{
    \stepcounter{g\Roman{character}}
    \global\@namedef{#3}{{\namefont #2}\xspace}
    \global\n@me@ppend@nddef{#3}{\@ppendname}{%
        \if@drverse
            {\speakstab\speaksfont #2\speaksdel\par\nobreak\addvspace{-\parskip}}
        \else
            \item[#2\speaksdel]
        \fi}
    \global\n@me@ppend@nddef{gpersona@\Roman{character}}{%
        @\Roman{g\Roman{character}}}{\castfont #1}
    %\NewPerson
}
\makeatother

\begin{CharacterGroup}{TeX.SX}
\GCharacter{A Character}{A Character}{character}
\end{CharacterGroup}

\begin{document}
\DramPer

\lipsum[1] % Compilation fails with only \DramPer in document
\end{document}
```

Inside *.sty files `@`'s are letters, in an ordinary *.tex file are not, hence local switch of their meaning.